# Why am I getting this error in Oauth 2 access token code using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, authentication, plsql, oauth-2.0, rest

I am able to get the access token using postman but I am not able to using the PL/SQL Block. I get unauthorized back as response even when I use the same client id and client secret. Please let me know what am I doing wrong. I am working on oracle 12c. Thank you.

```
DECLARE

  http_req     UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  http_resp    UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  l_ClientID varchar2(1000) := 'clientid';
  l_ClientSecret varchar2(1000) := 'clientsecret';
  l_AuthResponse UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  l_AuthRaw VARCHAR2 (32767);
  l_AuthReqBody varchar2(2000);
  v_url varchar2(2000) := 'http://someurl/oauth/token';
  l_ClientCredetial VARCHAR2(1000) := l_ClientID || ':' || l_ClientSecret;

BEGIN

   l_AuthReqBody := 'grant_type=client_credentials'|| chr(38) || 'client_id=' || l_ClientID || chr(38) || 'client_secret=' || l_ClientSecret;

   -- Set Oracle Wallet, which works fine

   http_req := utl_http.begin_request(
                   v_url ,
                   'POST',
                   'HTTP/1.1');

  utl_http.set_header (http_req, 'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   utl_http.write_text (http_req, l_AuthReqBody);

   l_AuthResponse := utl_http.get_response(http_req);

   utl_http.read_text(l_AuthResponse, l_AuthRaw);
   sp_memo_temp('1 l_AuthRaw: '||l_AuthRaw);

  UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_AuthResponse);
  UTL_HTTP.end_request (http_req);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to access a REST webservice with OAuth and I just needed to set a header with my token, utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', l_token).